# Why aren't the lines showing up on my graph in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line-plot

[image: The plot]

I used the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats
import time
```

Comment: please do not post images of code, use text

Comment: See [ask], which specifically says not to use screenshots of code/data/errors.

Comment: Can you check the values in the `n` and `results`?

Comment: looks like `n` is a number, so is `results[…]`. In which case, `plot` wouldn’t draw anything because it’s trying to draw a line with just one given point. You can try add option`marker='o'` to see that point.